# How to write a method using hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

How to implement a `boolean contains(T elem){}` method in a hashtable?

This is what I have:

```
public boolean contains (T elem) {
    if ( this.table != null || this.size != 0 ) {
        this.table = null;
        size--;
        return false;
    }
    else { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you emptying the `table` when calling `contains`? That doesn't seem like what it should do.

Comment: `contains` shouldn't change any variables.  If you're changing anything in `contains`, it can't be right.

Comment: You haven't hashed the element as the key. Afterwards, you need to use `.equals()`(which `element` would have to override) to determine if any of the elements in those buckets at that location of the `HashTable` match the element(this may depend on implementation) your searching for and return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not it found a match.

Comment: @AliasCartellano what do you mean with "hashes the element as the key"? I am new to programming and java. Please explain more.

Comment: You need to hash the element to determine what index it belongs to in the `HashTable` then compare the value at that location with the index. Try looking at some [psuedocode](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_data_structure.htm).

Comment: Also modulo divide the hash by the table size.